# C# project with app.config added as reference in web app web.config

Tags: asp.net

I have a C# project with one `app.config` file in it. I have added its reference into my web application. Web application has one `web.config` file.

I have added below line into it.

```
<appSettings>
    <add  key="keyname" value="This is the value."/>
</appSettings>.
```

But while execution, the pplication is not able to read this **keyname** key from appsettings.

Please help.

Comment: **SHOW US THE CODE!**

Comment: Using below lines I am trying to read the content. ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["keyname"]. But getting null exception.

Comment: If that entry is really in your `web.config`, and you're reading this from the web application, this *must work*. I'm afraid there's something more to this that you're not telling us yet .....

Comment: The above appsettings are into app.config file. And the I am trying to read the this key within the cs project. This csproject is added in web application.

Comment: What *kind* of project is this? The .NET config system only works for full applications - class library `app.config` files are **not** evaluated ....

Comment: class library is used as common for multiple web applications. so it has some common or unique settings for itself. So I can not add these settings into web.config file of web application.

Comment: You actually **must** add those settings into the `web.config`, since the class library itself cannot have a separate `app.config` - but you just said in your previous comment that these app settings are in `app.config` ..... have you added them to the `web.config` already and tried?

Comment: Yes I know I should be adding it to web.config but the project requires such settings to be kept within the cs project. So I tried with app.config.

Comment: As I said - that **will NOT** work - .NET class libraries **cannot** have their own `app.config` and read values from there.

Comment: Any other way to keep these settings within cs project.